# How to separate list input by comma?

Tags: python, list

So I'm making a A1Z26 cipher decoder where I could enter the numbers in and it'll return a corresponding letter, e.g. 8,5,12,12,0 --> h,e,l,l,o.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to make python take each number as input as opposed to splitting them into digits.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:
Here's the code I've written so far:`

```
dic = {dictionary that translates numbers to letters}
mid = []
output = []

input = raw_input("Enter the code here: ")
splitinput = list(input)

for i in splitinput:
    if i != ",":
        mid.append(i)

mid = [int(i) for i in buffer]

for i in mid:
    output.append(dic[i])


print output
```

So for it to stop splitting each number into digits I would need to use something other than the list function.

Comment: What code have you currently written?

Comment: give an example of the input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found it. This is the code that gives me the desired output if anyone will be interested:

```
inv_alphabet = {contains the mapping of each number to letter}
output = []

code_input = str(raw_input("Enter your cipher here: "))
split_code = code_input.split(",")

split_code = [int(i) for i in split_code]

for i in split_code:
    output.append(inv_alphabet[i])

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
myint = 123456789
mystr = str(myint)
print(','.join(mystr[::2]))
```